# arranging StandardTitleBar elements

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Can anybody help me how to arrange StandardTitlebar elements,for example I want battery indicator to be leftmost and network indicator rightmost,and clock to be center of status bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. According to [StandardTitlebar API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/StandardTitleBar.html),

> You cannot change the order of components in the standard title bar. The positions are fixed to the order listed above. The order in which you call the add functions has no bearing on the position or order of these components.

So you have to stick to the order specified in API. 
Only option for you to position fields is to create your own custom manager and add it to MainScreen using setTitle(). But then again I am not sure how will you create Battery, Clock and network indicator. BB doesn't provide any API for these fields.